# englarge image upon hover using html

Tags: html

I am new to all of this and wanted to know how to enlarge my image when I hover over it.

So far I have tried this.

```
<ul class="enlarge">
  <li>
    <img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="St John's" />
    <span>
      <img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/St-Johns-Pop-up.jpg" />
      <br />St John's, Baldock
    </span>
  </li>
```

All this does is makes a small image and a large image. I don't know how to use css so if you respond please can it be in HTML code.

Also the HTML code that is coming up in the text box beneath is not what I have written and don't know how to change that.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Sarah

Comment: <ul class="enlarge"><li><img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" width="261px" height="174px" alt="St John's"/><span><img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg"</span><br/>St John’s, Baldock</li>
</ul>

Comment: you can't do it with just html

Comment: Try something like [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into `CSS` or `Javascript` as otherwise hovering is a near-impossible task. Heres what you can do:

First off, remove the span and use a `class` to identify the `thumbnail`.

```
<ul class="enlarge">
    <li>
        <img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="St John’s" class="thumbnail" />
        <img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/St-Johns-Pop-up.jpg" class="large-image" />
        <br />St John’s, Baldock
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now add some CSS, don't worry, it's rather simple. What we want to accomplish is that when you hover over the thumbnail, we display the larger image. So on hover, we hide the thumbnail and show the larger image. But since we're hiding the thumbnail, we can't hover on it, so we also want to keep displaying the larger image until our cursor moves away from it entirely.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .enlarge .thumbnail + img {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Hovering over the thumbnail, hide the thumbnail */
    .enlarge .thumbnail:hover {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Hovering over the thumbnail, show the large image and keep showing it when hovering over the image */
    .enlarge .thumbnail:hover + img,
    .enlarge .thumbnail + img:hover {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

The `.enlarge` select all elements with `class="enlarge"`, the `.thumbnail` does the same for the class `thumbnail`. `img` selects every image element, and the `+` in the middle says to select any element that comes directly *after* the preceding, so the line simply reads: select any `img` element that comes after a `.thumbnail` element that is inside a `.enlarge` element. The `:hover` seems self-explanatory, but here goes anyway: a `:` selector is called a pseudo-selector and defines a state or `meta` element (meta elements are elements you can stylise but aren't really there, like `::before` and `::after`). Metas usually use a `::`. There are other pseudo-states as well, like `:active`. The style that is defined here will only be invoked when that state is invoked. Its the easiest way to make a hover happen!

You can, however, do this with just one image as well:

```
<img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="St John’s" class="enlarge-image" />
<br />St John’s, Baldock
```

It simplifies your styling a lot:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .enlarge-image {
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* Show full size on hover */
    .enlarge-image:hover {
        /* This can be any size you want it to be as well. */
        width: auto;
    }
</style>
```

A couple of notes on your code: first off, be aware you have typographic quotes (`”` compared to regular quotes: `"`) surrounding your image source. This can lead to issues. Second, an image size is always in pixels unless defined in `%`, so ommit `px` from your width and height.

```css
.enlarge-image {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
.enlarge-image:hover {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="St John’s" class="enlarge-image" />
<br />St John’s, Baldock
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start learning css. It is the only way to fix it.

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
.picture{
  width : 150px;
  height : 100px;
 }
.picture:hover{
  width : 200px;
  height : 150px;
 }
    </style>
</head>
<ul class="enlarge">
    <li>
        <img src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" class="picture"               alt="St John’s " />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do I run this so that I can have 3 pictures in a line? I tried just amending the hover size and then adding in the different pictures but I keep getting the first picture in hover and then the rest in large pictures.

Comment: I dont really understand it, but do you add the class='"picture" to the other images?

Comment: I just copied and pasted what you gave me, changed the hover size and repeated just adding in the new photos. I got one hover picture and then the other 2 came up large. This is the webpage. http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/educational/

Comment: Strange, because I can add multiple images with the over function. Can you send me the code with the multiple images?

Comment: <img style="padding: 1px; border: thin solid black;" src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" alt="" width="261" height="174" /><img style="padding: 1px; border: thin solid black;" src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0087.jpg" alt="" width="261" height="174" />

Comment: ><img style="padding: 1px; border: thin solid black;" src="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/St-Johns-5.jpg" alt="" width="261" height="174" /> <a href="http://bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Optimized-DSC_0077.jpg" target="_blank"> </a>

Comment: Not sure if that's what you wanted I cant add it all in one as its 63 characters too long.

Comment: you forgot to add the class="picture" in the img tag <img src="bhushan.wcukdev.co.uk/wp_239/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/…; alt="" class="picture" /> try to move the style to the style sheet in your head tag

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Above answer  are correct. I am providing you some link which will help you.
```

http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm

[http://jsfiddle.net/4AM3S/](https://jsfiddle.net/4AM3S/)

Comment: The top link doesn't work and I have tried the bottom link before, this just gives me a small and big picture. I know Im doing something wrong but I cant figure it out. When I use Jari's code it works for one picture but when I apply this to the 3 that I have I just get the one hover picture and the rest are just really big pictures. Sorry to be a pain but this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, but now it looks rubbish. Anyone know how to hide the other photos when I hover and enlarge one photo as they just move around the larger photo.

That's what I have. I still cant post a photo of what it looks like. Also the last photo when you hover over it it flickers, is this my code or the size of the screen?